# How to add TokenAuthentication authentication classes to Django FBV

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I know how to create token authentication in CBV of Django Rest Framework. See a random example below

```
class Something(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.SomeSerializer
    queryset = Some_Model.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

I want to create a token authentication for my FBV. Is that possible. Below are my views. My whole project is on Django rest Framework. Only the below function renders in a regular django template template. I want to add token authentication to the below function

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
def some_function(request, pk):
    #code below
```

Comment: You also need to add `@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))` for the Token Authentication to be actually even considered.

Comment: @invinciblycool thank you that worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A special thanks to @JPG and @invincibly cool without which I could not have gotten this done below is the code

```
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def some_function(request, pk):
    #code below
```

Comment: I forgot to add `permission_classes` decorator

Comment: @JPG thankyou so much I was wondering why you retracted your answer. This code is derived just because of you.